# Is it possible to set an ASP.NET Owin security cookie's ExpireTimeSpan on a per-user basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app using Owin cookie authentication. Currently, we set up cookie authentication as follows:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var timeoutInMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cookie.timeout-minutes"]);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutInMinutes),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Sessions/Logout")
        });
    }
}
```

We have a feature request to allow our application's admins to customize session timeouts within their organizations. However, the configuration code above executes at the MVC application level and our app is multi-tenant. Does anyone know of a way to set the ExpireTimeSpan of a user's session on a per-user basis, either during authentication or by overriding an Owin pipeline event somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The authentication options contains a property called `Provider`. You can either set this to the default provider and use one of the method overrides such as `OnResponseSignIn` to modify the settings of the login, or you could implement your own `ICookieAuthenticationProvider` and do the same.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnResponseSignIn = signInContext =>
        {
            var expireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

            if (signInContext.Properties.Dictionary["organization"] == "org-1")
            {
                expireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45);
            }

            signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(expireTimeSpan);
        }
    }
});
```

You could either check the incoming claim to see how the session should be handled or you could add custom data to your sign in call.

```
context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{
    Dictionary =
    {
        { "organization", "org-3" }
    }
}, new ClaimsIdentity());
```

You could even set `ExpiresUtc` on the sign in call if you really wanted, though it might be best to leave that logic in the authentication provider so it's easier to manage.

Comment: ExpiresUtc didn't seem to work for me, though this looks promising.

Comment: I'm a little bit baffled by how this works; specifically, this approach provided a sliding expiration, and I don't see how that's possible.  OnResponseSignIn is only called once, when logging in, and the ExpiresUtc is set to a specific clock time. So if I logged in at 12:01, ExpiresUtc gets set to 12:16... but if I make a request at 12:05, although a breakpoint in OnResponseSignIn is never hit again, my login does not expire at 12:16 but stays valid until 12:20.  My cookie should still say 12:16 despite the subsequent request, so how is that possible?

Comment: @Grank the cookie middleware handles adjusting the expiration time. So if you have `SlidingExpiration` and `AllowRefresh` set to `true` then the middleware will calculate what the session duration was, and push the time out from there. The code for this is in the `AuthenticateCoreAsync` method in http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs

Comment: This method does indeed work, as the ``AuthenticationProperties`` dictionary is being serialized into the cookie itself, hence when a refresh occurs and the ``OnResponseSignin`` is called again, you'll have access to the original value you've set up at login. I've used the same mechanism as the one described here, but I've decided to store the the computed  expiration timespan in a custom entry on the ``AuthenticationProperties`` dictionary at login. No reason to add additional logic to compute it every time.

Comment: As much as I struggled to understand Katana, answers like this make me love it.  I wish I could upvote this answer twice.  Just one point, perhaps its worth checking that `signInContext.Properties.Dictionary["organization"]` is not null before attempting to read its value.  I had an exception thrown here, but it didn't bubble up.  Thanks anyway!