# Azure Active Directory Stay Sign in OR Remember Me Option

Tags: azure-active-directory, remember-me

We are planning to move to Azure Active Directory from current custom forms based authentication. In process wondering if below is possible (Custom forms authentication implements below). How do I achieve this using Azure Active Directory?

Currently company web site has this feature and members can optionally choose to stay sign in. Those who choose to stay sign in are issued persistent cookie for 90 days. Member when accessing member area again on that device are not required to put in their user name and password.

Also, other sites like My Account/Maintain Profile  does not offer stay sign in feature though they both use  the same credential store. But for convenience of members if they are already signed in to Website and go to My Account/Maintain profile application, their user name is pre-populated.  Member is still required to put in their password.

Now in new paradigm, where both Website and My Account/Maintain Profile application will be using AAD for authentication, how will we achieve above functionality i.e.

- Selectively have stay sign in feature for some applications. The feature is optional and for members who choose to click this are not required to sign in again for 90 days on that device.
- If members is already signed in to one asset and is required to sign in to another asset, have the user ID pre-populated.

Answer (score 2):

The session created by Azure AD on user login can't really be controlled by the user.  It has fairly static rules about session length, persistence, etc. Shortly, Azure AD tenant administrators will be able to control some of these aspects through config. But it's not really up to the user.

With that said, you can definitely achieve the experience you describe in your app.  You would have to ask the user in your own UX (as opposed to the Azure AD login UX) if they want to 'stay signed in'.  I would do it by:

- Having a checkbox next to the login button
- Encode the value of the checkbox in the `state` parameter of the OpenID Connect authorize request (OWIN - use `AuthenticationProperties`)
- When Azure AD sends back its `id_token` response, decode the checkbox value from the `state` (OWIN - OWIN should take care of this for you)
- Use the value to set the length/persistence of the session cookie issued by your app (OWIN - retrieve the checkbox value from the `AuthenticationProperties` as shown here: [Is it possible to set an ASP.NET Owin security cookie's ExpireTimeSpan on a per-user basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376285/is-it-possible-to-set-an-asp-net-owin-security-cookies-expiretimespan-on-a-per)

For the other paradigm, you can pre-fill the Azure AD sign in page by passing the `login_hint` query parameter on the OpenID Connect authorize request.  I leave it to you to figure out how to keep track of the user's username.

Comment: Thanks for hint/idea! Will try this out and update later.